# vue cli not installing , tried using yarn and npm none is working?

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js, npm, vue-cli

i have been trying to install vue cli

am getting this error :

npm WARN deprecated request@2.88.2: request has been deprecated, see https://github.com/request/request/issues/3142
npm WARN deprecated resolve-url@0.2.1: https://github.com/lydell/resolve-url#deprecated
npm WARN deprecated urix@0.1.0: Please see https://github.com/lydell/urix#deprecated
npm ERR! Unexpected end of JSON input while parsing near '...b\n/0ygjrhbcRx2VetexZ'

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\ekikere\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache_logs\2020-07-28T23_29_37_356Z-debug.log

Comment: what is the exact command you are running?

Answer (score 0):

This is a problem related to npm. You can get this error when the cache file gets corrupted. Clearing the cache solves the problem. Can you try this?

```
npm cache clean --force
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it

Answer (score 0):

you can clear cache by running these command :

`npm cache clean --force`

- linux system:

run command as root

```
sudo npm install -g @vue/cli
```

- windows system

open command prompt as **adminstrator** then run :

```
npm install -g @vue/cli
```